# Creating a ship log... What method to use? JAVA

Tags: java

I'm working on my first big project and one thing I need to do is create a log of all the ships in a game and all their stats, their name, class etc... There must be at least over 100 ships. I thought about using a Hashmap, but I would need more than one value per key. I thought about doing a bunch of string arrays, but I think that would take too much memory. Should I read the values in from a .txt file? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, and thank you for your time. :D

Comment: Here is a hint - if you read the values from a text file where will you read them to?

Comment: The answer depends.  Is each ship it's own `Class` are you trying to maintain the information about the ships in some other kind of structure (which is what it sounds likes)?

Comment: No each ship is not its own class. I'm trying to make each one only an object containing the sats and name etc. of it, I think.

Comment: As I read your comment that would make each `Ship` a class, from which you create instances of to generate individual objects ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the unique identifier for a `ship`? You can simply create a hashmap using that unique identifier as the `key` and the `ship` instance as the value. In addition, there is nothing preventing you from using a `MultiMap` to store a collection of values at each key if that makes semantic sense. But this question is rather poorly defined with respect to what you actually want this 'log' to do.

Comment: the log is simply storing information to be referenced by the ships name to retrieve its stats. thank you for answering!

Comment: But does every ship have a unique name? If it does not, then this is not so useful a thing to do. Instead each ship should have some kind of unique identifier, and the name should be encoded inside the `ship` class.

Comment: Then sure, go ahead and use a `HashMap<string, ship>`